# Using common code without inheritance on RectJS components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example,

```
const Shelf1 = () =>{
  const mouseDown = (e) =>{
    console.log("mouseclick");
  }
}
const Shelf2 = () =>{
  const mouseDown = (e) =>{
     console.log("mouseclick");
  }
}
const Shelf3 = () =>{
   const mouseDown = (e) =>{
     console.log("mouseclick");
  }
}
```

I want to do the completely common function for three components.

I guess normally I should make inheritance class,

However some article says you should not use inheritance for react components.

So, I just wondering, what should I use for this simple purpose?

One idea is, making a static class and use function from each components,

```
class MyFunc {
   static click(){
      console.log("mouse click"); // call this from each components like MyFunc.click();
   }
}
```

However I am not sure it is the best practice, It looks like inferitance is better.

Could you give some advices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static code would be the last options that I would choose. Here are some common patterns that you will find used in modern libraries

1. HoC style - this gives another component a very high level of control over the sub components

```
const addMouseDownEvents = (Component,config) => props => {

  return <Component {...props} onMouseDown={onMouseDown}/>
}
```

2. Hooks style - reusable and flexible. You can compose the functions together. IE the component has a onMouseDown event that calls the hook's onMouseDown event

```
const useMouseDown = config => {
  const onMouseDown = () => {...}

  return {
    onMouseDown
  }
}

const MyComponent = props => {
  const { onMouseDown } = useMouseDown();

  ....
}
```

I would strongly recommend using the hooks pattern since it is the most re-usable and easiest to use. HoCs are only needed if there needs to be a visual element in the DOM re-used.

Comment: Thank you very much, I choose hooks Example. It worked after try and erorr.